# Making a webserver

Tags: webserver, hosting

I have an idea to make a Hosting server in my home the problem is I have no idea what I need to make it?
My question is what is the minimum **hardware** and **software** to make a simple a webserver*?

Comment: The minimum hardware and software to make a simple web server is a modem, a router, a PC and a piece of [web server software](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_server_software). If you to do actual hosting (like a traditional web host, rather than managing everything yourself), you will likely need a hosting control like CPanel, Zpanel or Sentoral and any software they require to support them. Some FTP software would likely be warranted as well.

Comment: any PC can be used ?

Comment: For light traffic and simple web pages, almost any network-capable computer will do, e.g. a single board computer (SBC) such as an RPi or similar can suffice.  For software there are simple web-server programs for light traffic and simple web pages.  Are you detecting a trend in the answer?  Vote to close because your question is too vague / too broad.

Comment: Hypothetically, yes. Generalizing a bunch, the basic difference between a "server" and a "regular" computer is the power of the hardware (how much "computing" it can handle) and some differences in the typical OSes they run. But those differences don't prevent you from running the basic software you need to do what you're asking.

Comment: Glad to help illuminate you. =)

Answer (score 1):

> **what is the minimum hardware and software to make a simple webserver?**

Hardware: An Ethernet cable and something like a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/). It is debatable whether an [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebServer) with an Ethernet "shield" would be considered simpler or more minimal.

Software: I run [thttpd](https://acme.com/software/thttpd/) on mine. It's pretty minimal. I think thttpd packages are available in the usual way (apt get) or you can [build from source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=14759).

Of course if you want your webserver to support 500 concurrent 4K video streams, a minimal solution isn't what you really want.